# Downloading files using vala

Tags: file, download, vala

I need to use Vala to upload the files. To do this, I use the File class:

```
File server_file = File.new_for_uri("https://mysi.te/mydir/myfi.le");
File local_file = File.new_for_path("~/mydir/myfi.le");
server_file.copy(local_file, FileCopyFlags.OVERWRITE);
```

This method worked for download .jar files and reads .json files without download but stopped working when I tried to download the file: `mysi.te/assets/objects/72/<sha1>`
The program hangs on a call to the `server_file method.copy` and nevadae no exceptions or ochibi. **Help please!**

*P. s. downloadable file-text.*

Comment: If you want help debugging this you're going to need to post a real URL. Also, an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @nemequ Okay, but how does that help?

Comment: @nemequ But the link leads to a plain text file without an extension (its name is sha1 cache)

Comment: One URL works, another doesn't… it seems pretty likely that the difference between the two may be relevant. It doesn't really matter if it's the data you actually want to use, as long as it reproduces the problem. Which is also why you should post an MCVE as well.

Comment: @nemequ I don't know what the problem is.. In the browser, this file is downloaded immediately, the link is correct, and the program hangs on any attempt to read from the stream.

Comment: Neither do I; that's why I asked you to post a complete test case.